# Unable to produce testing version on Android phone, can only access the last release before the testing one

Tags: android, flutter, google-play

I have tried all day to access the test version of the app that I've been working on. When I open the settings page to see what version I am looking at, it always says 1.0.22 when the testing version is 1.0.23.

First I tried open testing, and it went through review, but for many hours until I stopped checking the link to the testing version only brought me to 1.0.22.

I tried internal testing, and that link I got at least looked promising in terms of the initial screen that you see from that link. However, it brought me to 1.0.22.

How do I access the testing version (1.0.23) and stop opening the last release from 10/2020? This is process is not straight forward.

Comment: You've added yourself as a tester in Internal test?

Comment: Technically, I added my roommate's bc I don't have an android phone. I made them a Google developer to make sure that the link worked.

Comment: Okay. Open that link from the mobile phone and accept the program. Then it takes around a maximum of 30 minutes to show up. Hope your friend is logged in with the right email to play store